# Precision resistor measurement

Tags: resistors

I have received the data pack for 0.05 ohm +/-0.1%.

How should I read the measured resistance values by the provided RC1 and RC2 (resistance record) ppm?

Comment: Ppm stands for parts per million. So 0.1% equal 100 ppm.

Comment: @user263983 It’s ppm/K. Temperature drift.

Answer (score 2):

If your question (as in the title) is how to measure a 0.05\$\Omega\$ resistor, you will need to use [4-wire (Kelvin) measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing). It's a built-in capability of many bench-top multimeters. Image from Wikipedia:

[image]

The 4-wire method eliminates the effect of resistance of the test leads. 0.1% of 50m\$\Omega\$ is only 50\$\mu\Omega\$ so this is essential.

Lacking that type of instrument you can simply drive a known current through the device under test and measure the voltage. You need both measurements (current and voltage) to be very accurate, since you will calculate R = V/I. The datasheet and application notes from the resistor supplier may indicate how exactly the measurement is taken (terminal placement). You might pick a relatively high current such as 1A in order to get a relatively high voltage to measure, in contrast to a typical multimeter that might pass mA or less.